# A closed set without isolated points

Tags: general-topology

Let $F$ be a nonempty closed set of reals and denote by $I$ the set of its isolated points.

By definition, $F\setminus I$ is dense-in-itself.

> Is it true that $F\setminus I$ is closed?

Comment: $F\setminus I$ is closed, but is **not** dense-in-itself in general.  Example: $F=\{0\}\cup \{1/n|n=1,2,\ldots\}$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. If $x\in I$, then $\{x\}$ is an open subset of $F$. Since $I=\bigcup_{x\in I}\{x\}$, $I$ is an open subset of $F$ and therefore $F\setminus I$ is closed.

Comment: Clear, concise, nice!

Comment: Wah, that was even faster, nice one!

Comment: @Ikuyuki I suppose that you meant “accept” and not “except”.

Comment: @Nduccio When I first read your question, I felt tempted to edit it in order to add the `Real-analysis` tag to it, but then I noticed that I was able to answer your question without any reference to the reals.

Comment: Your proof is correct, but I feel you should add a step. You showed $F\setminus I$ is closed in $F$. That $F\setminus I$ is closed (in $\mathbb{R}$) follows since $F$ is closed.

Comment: @mathworker21 I thought that the OP meant “closed in $F$”. Otherwise, you are right, of course.

Comment: Yes I mean accept @José Carlos Santos

Comment: @mathworker21 you are right, but that's easy to do!

Answer (score 4):

Let $a\notin F\setminus I$. Then $a\in I$ or $a\notin F$. In the first case, there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $a$ such that $U\cap F=\{a\}$; in the second case, there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $a$ such that $U\cap F=\emptyset$. At any rate $U\cap (F\setminus I)=\emptyset$. We conclude that the complement of $F\setminus I$ is open.

---

ALternatively, for each $a\in I$, pick $U_a$ open such that $F\cap U_a=\{a\}$. Then $F\setminus I=F\setminus\hat I$, where $\hat I:=\bigcup_{a\in I}U_a$ is open. Closed minus open is closed.

Comment: That was fast and very clear, thank you